# How to watch a movie I rented on my Macbook on my iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, movie

I rented the documentary movie Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine a few hours ago, and was able to watch it on iTunes on the Mac.  When I tried to watch it on iPad, I do not see a Rental tab in the Videos app.

According to this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201611
this should be the way to do it:

[image]

But the 2nd line says: find the movie "on the device you used to rent it"... so does that mean if I use my Macbook to rent it, I can't view it on my iPad?

I can find it in iTunes store on the iPad, and if I tap rent, it will ask me if I want to pay $6.99 to rent it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [same support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201611):

> If you rented the movie on your computer, but want to watch it on an iOS device, connect the devices and sync using USB. When you move a rented movie from your computer, it will disappear from your computer’s iTunes library. *You can move the movie between devices as often as you want, but you can only have it on one device at a time.*
>
> If you rented the movie on your iOS device or Apple TV, you can’t move it to any other device.
>
> To watch an HD movie, you need to play it on a supported device: your computer, iPhone 4 or later, iPad, iPod touch (4th generation or later), or TV using Apple TV.

Comment: I suppose if I buy it, then I can watch it on any of my authorized devices, versus if I rent it, then it is a different set of rules. I really just wanted to see how the resolution is on iPad...